# TypeError: contract.methods.balanceOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, blockchain, smartcontracts, web3js

I am trying to get the balance of a specific NFT of a wallet but i am getting the error "TypeError: contract.methods.balanceOf is not a function"

This is the code i am using to do it

```
        const main = async () => {
            await connect()
            contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, ADDRESS)

            const balance = Number(await contract.methods.balanceOf(account).call())
        }
```

What am i doing wrong?

I have looked into the documentation but i can't find why it's an issue

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71813026/6133426) help in any way?

Comment: This is exactly what i am doing and it's not working

Comment: What do you get if you log the `contract.methods` to the console?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that either the ABI is not included with the function or the contract definition is missing with this function,

comment the contract address if it still has the issue,